# How to run crontab job every week on Sunday

Tags: linux, cron

I'm trying to figure out how to run a crontab job every week on Sunday. I think the following should work, but I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Is the following correct?

```
5 8 * * 6
```

Comment: The question is about 'sunday' but the answer accepted is about 'saturday'. ¿?

Comment: Use [https://crontab.guru/](https://crontab.guru/) site to create any cron expression.

Answer (score 584, accepted):

Here is an explanation of the crontab format.

```
# 1. Entry: Minute when the process will be started [0-60]
# 2. Entry: Hour when the process will be started [0-23]
# 3. Entry: Day of the month when the process will be started [1-28/29/30/31]
# 4. Entry: Month of the year when the process will be started [1-12]
# 5. Entry: Weekday when the process will be started [0-6] [0 is Sunday]
#
# all x min = */x
```

So according to this your `5 8 * * 0` would run 8:05 every Sunday.

Comment: To be more readable you can use one of `sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, or sat` for the day. This also saves you from having to choose between using `0` or `7` for sunday.

Answer (score 250):

To have a cron executed on Sunday you can use either of these:

```
5 8 * * 0
5 8 * * 7
5 8 * * Sun
```

Where `5 8` stands for the time of the day when this will happen: 8:05.

In general, if you want to execute something on Sunday, just make sure the 5th column contains either of `0`, `7` or `Sun`. You had `6`, so it was running on Saturday.

The format for cronjobs is:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

You can always use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) as a editor to check your cron expressions.

Comment: Just to help others avoid the silly mistake I have just made, and make sure you set the minute to something other than * or it will execute on every minute of that hour!

Answer (score 45):

Following is the format of the crontab file.

{minute} {hour} {day-of-month} {month} {day-of-week} {user} {path-to-shell-script}

So, to run each sunday at midnight (Sunday is 0 usually, 7 in some rare cases) :

```
0 0 * * 0 root /path_to_command
```

Comment: Voting up for mentioning how to specify the command to run each time. (The user column, however, needs to be omitted when editing via the "crontab" command.)

Comment: Sunday midnight is the 0 hour of Monday, i.e. `0 0 * * 1`.

Comment: @FredLoney thanks for pointing that out. "Astronomers and the military use a system in which midnight is 0 hours. In that system, tonight’s midnight is the first moment of tomorrow. But as for the rest of us – there’s no official answer. That’s why airlines always schedule flights for 11:59 p.m. or 12:01 a.m. – never midnight." via https://earthsky.org/space/edit-time

Comment: Just want to point out a potential "gotcha" is that by default cronjobs are scheduled in UTC time (4 hours ahead of east coast time)

Answer (score 29):

The crontab website gives the real time results display: https://crontab.guru/#5_8_*_*_0

[image]

Answer (score 6):

When specifying your cron values you'll need to make sure that your values fall within the ranges. For instance, some cron's use a 0-7 range for the day of week where both 0 and 7 represent Sunday. We do not(check below).

```
Seconds: 0-59
Minutes: 0-59
Hours: 0-23
Day of Month: 1-31
Months: 0-11
Day of Week: 0-6
```

reference: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: "we" ... who ? which program and version ?

Comment: Its directly from the link :D

Answer (score 5):

I think you would like this interactive website, which often helps me build complex Crontab directives: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 3):

**@weekly  work better for me!** 

`example,add the fellowing  crontab -e ,it will work in every sunday 0:00 AM
@weekly /root/fd/databasebackup/week.sh >> ~/test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Cron job expression in a human-readable way [crontab builder](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: Imho, this is not an answer as it does not add anything here, nor does it answer the question here in any way.

Answer (score 1):

10 * * * Sun

```
Position 1 for minutes, allowed values are 1-60
position 2 for hours, allowed values are 1-24
position 3 for day of month ,allowed values are 1-31
position 4 for month ,allowed values are 1-12 
position 5 for day of week ,allowed values are 1-7 or and the day starts at Monday.
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer at StackOverflow! Please be sure to check [Answering Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For instance, answer typically should has some new information that is missing in existing answers.

Comment: this will run 24 times on sunday, 10 minutes past the hour every hour.

Answer (score 1):

```
* * * * 0 

you can use above cron job to run on every week on sunday, but in addition on what time you want to run this job for that you can follow below concept :

* * * * *  Command_to_execute
- � � � -
| | | | |
| | | | +�� Day of week (0�6) (Sunday=0) or Sun, Mon, Tue,...
| | | +���- Month (1�12) or Jan, Feb,...
| | +����-� Day of month (1�31)
| +������� Hour (0�23)
+��������- Minute (0�59)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be really tempted to run using the @weekly keyword if you don't care what time of day this is run.  It should run every Sunday, and is definitely more readable.

@weekly some_script.sh

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.