# MySQL Query Automatic Email Sender

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a way to send recurring emails every week, month, year, etc. which contains MySQL Query Results. My queries are related to total revenues, and I would love these queries to be executed automatically, and sent via email automatically. I am open to any program or language or advice in which direction I should look to get this completed.

Comment: There's nothing in MySQL that sends mail, AFAIK. You'll need to write a script in some other language, like PHP or Python. It can perform the MySQL query and then send mail.

Comment: PHP has a built-in `mail()` function, there's also a library called `PHPMailer` you can install. Python has `smtplib`.

Comment: I'm sure you can find tutorials on how to use any of these things. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending email periodically through php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395506/sending-email-periodically-through-php-script)