# How to Create Auto Page Load Every Week Sunday using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi I try to Auto Load Page on Every Week Sunday Night 9.00pm using php mysql, Please Help Anyone.,**
**Here is my Execute code**

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","chat");
 // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
  $date_title = "TODAY";
  mysqli_query($con,"insert into date(date_title, date) values('$date_title', '$current_date')");
```

Comment: How to Execute this code every week sunday.,

Comment: Go for `CRON` job

Comment: Create cron job if using Linux or create schedule in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=> use cron job ..

Check this url :-

[How to run crontab job every week on Sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717930/how-to-run-crontab-job-every-week-on-sunday)

OR

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples