# cron to run on Saturday at 9:30 AM and Sunday at 10:30 AM

Tags: cron

How to schedule the job in cron to run on Saturday at 9:30 AM and Sunday at 10:30 AM in a single line,

30 9 * * 6  command
30 10 * * 7  command

how can I schedule it in a single line .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run crontab job every week on Sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717930/how-to-run-crontab-job-every-week-on-sunday)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If you had at lease one more duplicate (both start at 09 or both in Saturday)  then it is possible.