# Cron to run a job at 9:30am and 10:00am

Tags: cron

I am trying to write a cron where a job  runs twice a day. Once at 09:30am and 10:00am. I tried below one, but it runs with a gap of 1hr

```
0 30/30 9-10 * * ? --> runs at 09:30am & 10:30am
```

Searched multiple answers but unable to find any feasible solution. Can anyone suggest better way of doing this?

Comment: yeah, i will add two entries. Looks like that's the only better option

Answer (score 2):

for the way I see it, you can put in the cronjob two different entries, one for each scheduled job.
Here are the entries

```
0 10 * * *
```

and

```
30 9 * * *
```

By the way, your question is pretty much similar to this one: [cron to run on Saturday at 9:30 AM and Sunday at 10:30 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285418/cron-to-run-on-saturday-at-930-am-and-sunday-at-1030-am)
for which is already explained (not marked as best answer though) that is not possible.